# I can not request fileSystem,After I open a ***.doc by broswer whatever childBroswer or default webview

Tags: ios, cordova, safari

I am new to phonegap.I use cordova1.5 in ios.
If I open without *.doc by broswer ,everything will be ok,I still get fileSytem.
for example:gif,jpg,png,txt,html,pdf.

After I open *.doc by broswer,and close new view.
childBroswer(plugin),default webview,"file:///"(location),"http://"(net),all of them 
origin webview would not get fileSystem anymore .

Is it a bug? Is it normal?

Comment: do you have some code you can show as an example?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you managed to sort this out or not but:
Cordova extends NSMutableArray to add a pop method.  When you open a word document the viewer  overrides the Cordova version of pop, and when you return to the app Cordova starts using that version.

To make sure you have the same issue, create a plugin that calls [argument pop] a few times.  After loading the word document you should notice a change in behavior.

You can work around it by doing something like the code below, you need to store the store method before displaying the document, and call restore after you have closed it.

import objc/runtime.h
import objc/message.h

@implementation ...

static IMP cordovaPopImplementation = NULL;
static const char* cordovaPopEncoding = NULL;

+(void)storeCordovaPop
{
    Method popMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([NSMutableArray class], @selector(pop));
    if (!cordovaPopImplementation)
    {
        cordovaPopImplementation = method_getImplementation(popMethod);
        cordovaPopEncoding = method_getTypeEncoding(popMethod);
    }
}

+(void)restoreCordovaPop
{
    class_replaceMethod([NSMutableArray class], @selector(pop), cordovaPopImplementation, cordovaPopEncoding);
}